# RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.DoubleTensor but found type torch.FloatTensor for argument #2 'weight'

Tags: pytorch

My input tensor is torch.DoubleTensor type. But I got the RuntimeError below:

```
RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.DoubleTensor but found type torch.FloatTensor for argument #2 'weight'
```

I didn't specify the type of the weight explicitly(i.e. I did not init my weight by myself. The weight is created by pytorch). What will influence the type of weight in the forward process?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: After I transfer the input type to FloatTensor by .float(). The code can process correctly. But I still don't know what if I want doubletensor type input......

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The default type for `weights` and `biases` are `torch.FloatTensor`. So, you'll need to cast either your model to `torch.DoubleTensor` or cast your inputs to `torch.FloatTensor`. For casting your inputs you can do

```
X = X.float()
```

or cast your complete model to `DoubleTensor` as

```
model = model.double()
```

You can also set the default type for all tensors using

```
pytorch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.DoubleTensor')
```

It is better to convert your inputs to `float` rather than converting your model to `double`, because mathematical computations on `double` datatype is considerably slower on GPU.

Comment: Thanks for your answer very much!! BTW, I meet another problem about loading model. The IDE raise `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 918: ordinal not in range(128)` error when I use `model = torch.load("file.pth")` (ps: the .pth file comes from somewhere, and it was not trained by myself. The pth file trained by myself can be loaded using `torch.load`) .Thanks again!

Comment: That is probably because the model was created (and saved) using Python3, whose default encoding is utf-8, but you are using Python2. Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at top of your python file. Also it is not a good practice to save and load the complete model. This can break in a number of ways. For proper serialization of models see the [official post](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/serialization.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. But I am using python3... And I have added `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at top of my pyhton file. It doesn't work...

Comment: Then you can try to load the model in python2. For more details you can refer to [this issue](https://github.com/CSAILVision/places365/issues/25) on GitHub

Comment: for me with torch0.4.1 it is not pytorch.set(...) but torch.set(...)

Comment: It might have been updated in `0.4.0`, this worked with `0.3.1`. Edits welcomed, or I'll test myself on the latest version and update the answer

Answer (score 3):

I was also receiving exact same error. The root cause turned out to be this statement in my data loading code:

```
t = t.astype(np.float)
```

Here np.float translates to 64-bit float which maps to DoubleTensor. So changing this to,

```
t = t.astype(np.float32)
```

solved the issue.